# HTML: overlay div on table's td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

guys.

I'm trying to make div overlayed on my table's td, making users know that this td is not valid anymore.

The closest example I found is this: http://jsfiddle.net/YCZ3J/32/

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Overlay Tests</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3" style="position:relative"> 
        <tr class="row"> 
            <td class="cell"><img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_64.png" /></td>
            <td class="cell second">Text1</td>
            <td class="cell">Text2</td>
            <td class="cell">Text3</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr class="row">
              <td class="cell"><img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_64.png" /></td>
            <td class="cell second">Text1</td>
            <td class="cell">Text2</td>
            <td class="cell">Text3</td>         
        </tr>
    </table> 
    <div id="divOverlay" style=""><p>This is the overlay div.</p><p id="info"></p></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row').mouseover(function() {
        var $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');
        var bottomWidth = $(this).css('width');
        var bottomHeight = $(this).css('height');
        var rowPos = $(this).position();
        bottomTop = rowPos.top;
        bottomLeft = rowPos.left;
        $divOverlay.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: bottomTop,
            right: '0px',
            width: '66.7%',
            height: bottomHeight
        });

        $('#info').text('Top: ' + bottomTop + ' Left: ' + bottomLeft);
        $divOverlay.delay(1000).slideDown('fast');
    });
    $('#divOverlay').mouseleave(function() {
        var $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');
        $divOverlay.slideUp();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.cell{width: 80px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #000;}
.blind{display: none; background:#000; height: 80px; width: 320px;}
.second{display:none; background: #00f; height: 80px; width: 320px;}
#divOverlay { display: none; background-color:Silver; text-align:center;  position:absolute; z-index:10000; opacity:0.5; }
```

From the example above, I just want to remove mouserover effect, so that 
divOverlay could be over td at anytime.
I tried to modify Javascript code, but I failed.

Comment: remove the `$('.row').mouseover(function() {})` function and that effect wont take place

Comment: It doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/rrbcwo7w/ Could you check this jsfiddle?

Comment: *"..I'm trying to make div overlayed on my table's td, making users know that this td is not valid anymore..."* -- Don't do that. You will end up in unnecessary complications, as controlling table-cell heights and widths will become a nightmare for you with indeterminate content. You will end up with a large spaghetti of code just to try to make it responsive. -- You should keep it simple and just stylize the cells to indicate that they are not valid. Something like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/kxfjvn44/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use javascript for that. If you want to "grey out" a cell just use CSS.

In the fiddle example, the greyed out area is created with this bit of CSS

```
#divOverlay { display: none; background-color:Silver; text-align:center;  position:absolute; z-index:10000; opacity:0.5; }
```

The javascript is only for the mouse over effect.

EDIT: After waking up and using a clear non sleepy mind, i fiddled with your fiddle.

Here is the updated fiddle to achieve what you are looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/YCZ3J/338/

Comment: but it seems that javascript decides the width and height of the div, so that it would fit the size of the td. That CSS codes make the grey div be under the table.

Comment: You can add the styles from the script to the css to arrange for it to be in the correct spot. Sorry, should have pointed that out earlier.